# Does enabling hourly granularity for cost usage data in AWS provide realtime cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cost-explorer

We would like to enable Hourly Granularity for Cost/Usage in AWS.

However, by enabling this can we get real time cost day?

Question 1: Let us say, I run the cost report by Dec 2nd at 4 PM. Can I get the cost incurred between  3 PM to 4 PM? or do I have to wait for a day or some time to retrieve these details?

Question 2: If I have 1000 resources then for each hour - there will be 1000 usage records which will cost 0.01 per hour and 0.24 $ per day. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Let us say, I run the cost report by Dec 2nd at 4 PM. Can I get the cost incurred between 3 PM to 4 PM? or do I have to wait for a day or some time to retrieve these details?

I have noticed Billing data is lagging behind current time at about 10-24 hours.

When initially enabling Hourly granularity, it takes some time for the Cost explorer to begin showing hours.

> Question 2: If I have 1000 resources then for each hour - there will be 1000 usage records which will cost 0.01 per hour and 0.24 $ per day. Is my understanding correct?

When you go to enable the Hourly granularity, you will be given an estimate of how many records do you have. From this you can calculate roughly pricing for the month. I don't know if you cancel HG halfway through the period, if you are going to be billed only for the half period.